# Cant boot into Refind after installing Arch with Pop OS

Tags: debian, arch-linux, dual-boot, pop-os, refind

I installed Arch on my laptop that was running pop os using Anarchy Installer. I selected sda3 as the /boot sda10 as SWAP and sda11 as root partitions. After rebooting i was booted straight into Pop and I installed Refind. And ran refind-install. After rebooting I was booted straight into Pop and not refind. I tried changing with efibootmgr and nothing changed ( I ran efibootmgr again and the boot order was reseted)

efibootmgr output

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0003* grub
Boot0004* HDD0: Z06DPYUGT-TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0007* debian
Boot0008* Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

lsblk output

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0           7:0    0  76.5M  1 loop  /snap/john-the-ripper/535
loop1           7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop  /snap/core18/2409
loop2           7:2    0    47M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/16292
sda             8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    0   100M  0 part  
├─sda2          8:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─sda3          8:3    0   300M  0 part  
├─sda4          8:4    0   885M  0 part  
├─sda5          8:5    0  27.9G  0 part  /
├─sda6          8:6    0   977M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda7          8:7    0     1G  0 part  
├─sda8          8:8    0 361.7G  0 part  /home
├─sda9          8:9    0  1000M  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap 253:0    0 999.5M  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda10         8:10   0     3G  0 part  
└─sda11         8:11   0   251G  0 part
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.